# use variables from a C generated file

Tags: arrays, c

I have generated a C file which contains some arrays with their size as here:

nor.c (generated file)

```
const float nor[] = {
-0.0972819, 0.906339, -0.4112, -0.056471, 0.340899, -0.938402, -0.284611, 0.269598, -0.919953, 0.04142, -0.149024, -0.987966, 0.12454, -0.702485, -0.700717, 0.0027959, -0.188166, -0.982133 };

const unsigned int nor_size= 18;
```

when I called this array from my main file as shown here:

```
extern float nor[nor_size];
```

I got some error: cannot use nor_size as a const

how to solve this?

thanks

Comment: Why don't you generate `const float nor[size]` in the first place?

Comment: don't use `extern` in your main file, it belongs to header files

Comment: Gigo "cannot use nor_size as a const" --> was this the exact error?

Comment: Can you create a header file that contains a macro for the size?

Comment: Minor: `-0.0972819` and friends [deserve](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66631288/2410359) an `f` suffix.

Comment: In C you should use a `#define` for the size. The use of `const int ...` as numeric constants is a C++ thing that C doesn't support.

Comment: "when I called this array" make no sense. You don't "call" arrays. And if that file is generated, you should be standing up *two* `extern` (one for the array, and one for the size). e.g `extern const float nor[]; extern const unsigned int nor_size;`

Comment: Do you need the size at all? For an `extern` declaration it is not really required and if you want to calculate the size, you can calculate based on `nor_size` instead of `sizeof`.

Comment: I have only to use C file without h file

Comment: so the linker complains about that: unresolved external symbol

Comment: Take some time and create a [mre] and post exact error messages in the question

Comment: Remember that **StackOverflow is *not* a do-my-homework website**

Comment: Are you allowed to improve the software generating that C code?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes

Comment: Did you add both C files to your project? If you are allowed to improve that software, what about making it create that h file we are talking about as a first step? ;)

Comment: @Gerhardh I have to write some code to add it to .vcxproj.filter

Comment: @Gigo: and what forbids you to write such a code?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it uses xml format and I've never seen a c++ code that deals with xml format. did you?

Comment: Yes, you can find C++ libraries dealing with XML. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1542084/841108) question. And you can use other tools for that.

Comment: can you guide me a little bit? which libraries and which tools?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it's not a homework, it's a project that I'm working on it alone

Comment: Are you allowed to install a Linux distribution ([Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com/), [Debian](http://debian.org/), etc...) on your laptop? If yes, backup your important data before, then see [linuxfromscratch](http://linuxfromscratch.org/)

Comment: I work with windows

Comment: Then I cannot help you at all. Good luck. I am coding since 1974 but I never used Windows. I do recommend to meet another programmer in person and discuss with him with your laptop.

Comment: `const unsigned int nor_size= 18;` should be `const size_t nor_size = sizeof nor / sizeof *nor;`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  " coding since 1974 but I never used Windows" -->  Well free bird, I feel a [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0W1v0kOELA) coming on.

Answer (score 1):

> how to solve this?

The best would be for the generator of the nor.c file to also generate a corresponding nor.h file

```
#ifndef NOR_INCLUDE_GUARD
#define NOR_INCLUDE_GUARD

extern const float nor[18];
extern const unsigned int nor_size;

#endif
```

`main.c` uses that .h file

```
// Rather than
// extern float nor[nor_size];

// Include
#include "nor.h"
```

---

Also recommend the generator of the nor.c fil to append an `f` suffix to each constant.

Comment: I don't have to use h file

Comment: @Gigo "I don't have to use h file " --> OK, so you do not have to use a .h file, but it is still the best approach to use one.

Comment: I think that the c file in not in the path that's why I have an error when calling extern

Comment: @Gigo Does "don't have to use h file" mean that you "do not have a h file that you could use" or that you "are not specifically required to use h file"?

Comment: I'm not required to use . file

Comment: @Gigo Then after it was mentioned a few times, you are also not prevented from using a h file. Then, what stops you from doing it?

Answer (score 0):

In your `main.c` remove <strike>`extern float nor[nor_size];`</strike> then add

```
extern const float nor[];
extern const unsigned int nor_size;
```

and use them as appropriate. Indeed, `nor_size` might then be loaded (in [processor registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) at the machine code level) several times.

For more, **read [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)**, and later **some C standard like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)** or better.

If you are allowed to compile all your C (both handwritten and generated) code with some recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (or cross-compiler), invoke it at least [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `-Wall -Wextra -g` options.

### don't forget to read the documentation of your C compiler!

You also need to understand what is your [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)), and read its documentation. Maybe it could be [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/).

You could use some static source code analyzer, like [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), or [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/), or [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/). FYI, Bismon has 24604 lines of generated C code, and the [Bigloo](https://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/fp/Bigloo/) compiler has a lot of them too.

<sup>for Frama-C or Bismon, contact me by email to `basile.starynkevitch@cea.fr` and mention the URL of your question</sup>

#### Read also a good C programming book, like [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)

In 2021, you could be interested by the [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) project. It is strongly related to your question.

An interesting book describing a software which generates *all* the half-million lines of code of its C source (available [here](https://github.com/bstarynk/caia-pitrat/)) is Pitrat's [*Artificial Beings: the Conscience of a Conscious Machine*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848211015) (ISBN 978-1848211018). You could enjoy reading that book.

### See also [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) about generating C code.

You could also be interested by [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/). It is a [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) [parser generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler), mostly written in C, and generates C code. My recommendation is to download its source code and take inspiration from it.

By experience, when you are *generating* C code, it is easier to *improve* the generator (so that the generated C code compiles cleanly without warnings) that to change the generated C code. But do document well your C code generator. Read about [*partial evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) techniques.

Comment: it doesn't work, I think that the compiler doesn't see my generated c file

Comment: This means you are using your compiler wrongly. Did you read the documentation of your compiler?.

Comment: I use the visual studio compiler (VS2019)

Comment: why I have to read its doc, I write the code and then the compiler will do the job

Comment: Your question is showing that the compiler is not doing the job you expect.

Comment: I have to link the generated c file with my path i think

Comment: yes but what do you think about what I said?

Comment: I was not able to understand what you have said, and from my perspective, you said nothing and did not write enough.

Comment: There is no need to include a huge appendix with barely on-topic tool recommendations to every post. Newbies will _not_ benefit from static analysers and other more advanced tools, quite the opposite.

Comment: I disagree. Static analyzer tools are useful to newbies. Exactly like is useful the `-Wall -Wextra` options to `gcc`; and when coding a C code generator, trying to *avoid* warnings from GCC (or from some static analyzer tool) is a good habit to have. Look BTW into the coding rules related to bootstrapping GCC when contributing to it.